# Android HTTP Request Over Mobile Data

Tags: android, http

In one of my application I need to make HTTP request on 2G/3g/4g only. If device is connected to Wifi and mobile data both, I need to check and make HTTP request over mobile data. I don't want to turn ON/OFF Wifi.

If it can be done via Socket programming where we can transfer the traffic on cellular if both networks are available.

Any sample code or tutorial link will be highly appreciated.

Comment: The device automatically selects the fastest connection avaiable

Answer (score 1):

Try to implement this Connectivity java class and check your Mobile Data/WiFi.

```
public class Connectivity {


public static NetworkInfo getNetworkInfo(Context context){
    ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    return cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
}


public static boolean isConnected(Context context){
    NetworkInfo info = Connectivity.getNetworkInfo(context);
    return (info != null && info.isConnected());
}


public static boolean isConnectedWifi(Context context){
    NetworkInfo info = Connectivity.getNetworkInfo(context);
    return (info != null && info.isConnected() && info.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI);
}


public static boolean isConnectedMobile(Context context){
    NetworkInfo info = Connectivity.getNetworkInfo(context);
    return (info != null && info.isConnected() && info.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE);
}


public static boolean isConnectedFast(Context context){
    NetworkInfo info = Connectivity.getNetworkInfo(context);
    return (info != null && info.isConnected() && Connectivity.isConnectionFast(info.getType(),info.getSubtype()));
}


public static boolean isConnectionFast(int type, int subType){
    if(type==ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI){
        return true;
    }else if(type==ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE){
        switch(subType){
        case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_1xRTT:
            return false; // ~ 50-100 kbps
        case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_CDMA:
            return false; // ~ 14-64 kbps
        case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_EDGE:
            return false; // ~ 50-100 kbps
        case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_EVDO_0:
            return true; // ~ 400-1000 kbps
        case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_EVDO_A:
            return true; // ~ 600-1400 kbps
        case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_GPRS:
            return false; // ~ 100 kbps
        case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_HSDPA:
            return true; // ~ 2-14 Mbps
        case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_HSPA:
            return true; // ~ 700-1700 kbps
        case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_HSUPA:
            return true; // ~ 1-23 Mbps
        case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_UMTS:
            return true; // ~ 400-7000 kbps
        /*
         * Above API level 7, make sure to set android:targetSdkVersion 
         * to appropriate level to use these
         */
        case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_EHRPD: // API level 11 
            return true; // ~ 1-2 Mbps
        case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_EVDO_B: // API level 9
            return true; // ~ 5 Mbps
        case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_HSPAP: // API level 13
            return true; // ~ 10-20 Mbps
        case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_IDEN: // API level 8
            return false; // ~25 kbps 
        case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_LTE: // API level 11
            return true; // ~ 10+ Mbps
        // Unknown
        case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_UNKNOWN:
        default:
            return false;
        }
    }else{
        return false;
    }
 }

}
```

and check like below:

```
if(Connectivity.isConnectedWifi(Login.this)){
                //Implement your logic      

 }else if(Connectivity.isConnectedMobile(Login.this)){
                //Implement your logic              
}
```

**Update:**

Try to implement second way:

I don't think you can do this because in Android only one Network is active at any point of time. So for that first you need to check which network is active and then if it is a Wi-Fi one, then disconnect it, then Android will fallback to other one which will be 2G/3G (if there is no other wi-fi network available), then you can send your request which will go through 2G/3G network.outline might look like this:

```
 ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager)Context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
NetworkInfo ni = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
 if(ni == null)
//no connectivity, abort
if(ni.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI || ni.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIMAX) {
WifiManager wm = (WifiManager)Context.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
if( wm != null)
wm.disconnect();
//this will force android to fallback to other available n/w which is 3G
}
while(true) {
NetworkInfo ni = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
 if(ni != null && ni.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE && ni.isConnected())  {
  //send your http request
 break;
```

}
    //sleep for some time, so that android can connect you to other n/w
}

You might need to loop through all active n/w and disconnect them till you find 2G/3G network. I am assuming that there is just one Wi-Fi network and one 2G/3G network available.

Here you can customized as per your requirement and also used my `Connectivity.java` class and integrate over hee.

Comment: By these methods I can only check but I want to make HTTP request on 2G/3G if both connections available. How I can do this

Comment: Why don't you want to use wifi? I would think your users wouldn't be very pleased if they had wifi turned on only for your app to be wasting their data. Perhaps a better solution would be to prompt the user to turn off their wifi if it is turned on so the user knows what is going on.

Answer (score -1):

Use the below code

```
public class ConnectionDetector {

private Context _context;

public ConnectionDetector(Context context) {
    this._context = context;
}


public boolean isConnectingToInternet() {
    boolean haveConnectedWifi = false;
    boolean haveConnectedMobile = false;

    ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) _context
            .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo[] netInfo = cm.getAllNetworkInfo();
    for (NetworkInfo ni : netInfo) {
        if (ni.getTypeName().equalsIgnoreCase("WIFI"))
            if (ni.isConnected())
                haveConnectedWifi = true;
        if (ni.getTypeName().equalsIgnoreCase("MOBILE"))
            if (ni.isConnected())
                haveConnectedMobile = true;
    }
    return haveConnectedMobile;
}

}
```

It will connect internet only in mobile network.